# Set run-time cursor position in directory page dialog box - NSIS

Tags: nsis

I want to add at the end of the path the installation folder name of my App. I do it successfully after clicking the Browse button but, after many tentatives, I couldn't do it if I modify the text directly in the textbox.

```
Function .onVerifyInstDir
    Push $0
        FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
        GetDlgItem $0 $0 0x3FB
    ;in alternative for MUI >2.0 I could use directly $mui.DirectoryPage.Directory. Is it right?

    ;does path end with "\MyApp"?
    StrLen $R1 "\${APP_FOLDER_NAME}"
    StrCpy $R0 $INSTDIR "" -$R1
    StrCmp $R0 "\${APP_FOLDER_NAME}" +2

        ;add "\MyApp" after browse button clicking (OK)
    StrCpy $INSTDIR "$INSTDIR\${APP_FOLDER_NAME}"

        ;add "\MyApp" after typing directly into the textbox but the cursor position reset to the first character. Tried to solve saving the current cursor position and then reapply it (NOK)
        SendMessage $0 ${EM_GETSEL} null $1
          SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$INSTDIR"
    SendMessage $0 ${EM_SETSEL} $1 $1
FunctionEnd
```

I don't succeed of mantain the cursor where I'm modifying the path string and it reset always to the first char.

In a previous phase of install process I initialise the Install path as follow

```
StrCpy $INSTDIR "$APPDATA\${APP_FOLDER_NAME}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSIS is supposed to do this for you already.

From the docs:

> ... the part of this string following the last \ will be used if the user selects 'browse', and may be appended back on to the string at install time (to disable this, end the directory with a \ (which will require the entire parameter to be enclosed with quotes). If this doesn't make any sense, play around with the browse button a bit.

Meaning,

```
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\MyApp"
```

is not the same as

```
InstallDir "$ProgramFiles\MyApp\"
```

Setting the text in `.onVerifyInstDir` is not officially supported but this code somewhat works:

```
!define APP_FOLDER_NAME MyApp
Page Directory
Page InstFiles

!include WinMessages.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Function .onInit
StrCpy $INSTDIR "$APPDATA\${APP_FOLDER_NAME}"
FunctionEnd

Var InOnVerifyInstDir
Var SeenModal

Function .onVerifyInstDir
${IfThen} $InOnVerifyInstDir <> 0 ${|} Return ${|} ; Don't recurse into .onVerifyInstDir
!if ${MUI_SYSVERSION} >= 2.0
    StrCpy $0 $mui.DirectoryPage.Directory
!else
    FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $hWndParent
    GetDlgItem $0 $0 0x3FB
!endif

    System::Call 'USER32::GetActiveWindow()p.r2'
    System::Call 'USER32::GetFocus()p.r1'
    ${If} $1 P<> $0 
        ${If} $hWndParent P<> $2
            StrCpy $SeenModal 1
            Return
        ${EndIf}
        ${If} $SeenModal = 0
            Return
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
    StrCpy $SeenModal ""

    ;does path end with "\MyApp"?
    StrLen $R1 "\${APP_FOLDER_NAME}"
    StrCpy $R0 $INSTDIR "" -$R1
    ${If} $R0 != "\${APP_FOLDER_NAME}"
        StrCpy $InOnVerifyInstDir 1
        StrCpy $INSTDIR "$INSTDIR\${APP_FOLDER_NAME}"
        SendMessage $0 ${EM_GETSEL} "" "" $1
        IntOp $1 $1 >> 16    ; shift hiword
        IntOp $1 $1 & 0xffff ; mask possible sign bit
        SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$INSTDIR"
        SendMessage $0 ${EM_SETSEL} $1 $1
        StrCpy $InOnVerifyInstDir 0
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

but I would still recommend just using `InstallDir`.

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick response... but my need is not move the cursor to the end of textbox string. My goal is leave the cursor where the user is modifying the install string and that the last part of the install string is always "\MyApp", even if the user cancel or add chars everywhere in the install string.

Comment: If you want to append `\MyApp` no matter what, you could do it when the user leaves the page but that seems rather evil if you ask me.

Comment: Yes... I could append \MyApp, no matter what, using the custom event MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE but I don't like it either because the user wouldn't be aware of what the installer is doing... I suppose

Comment: Thanks @Anders... I tested your code. It works as expected except for the fact that, if I click the Browse button the text string in background is updated continuosly. For this reason, even if I click cancel in the folder dialog, the text string is updated anyway. How eliminate this drawback? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Jumpy73 I updated the code, it works better now. It can't handle it when you select just "c:\" but you are normally not allowed to install to the root anyway.

Comment: Thanks for code improvement. I tested it and it works as aspected, included the limitation you mentioned. What do you mean with "but I would still recommend just using InstallDir"? Is there an easier way to accomplish my need?

Comment: I just mean that forcing this suffix is unnecessary, normal users just install to the default path and advanced users know what they are doing.

Comment: Thanks @Anders, I understand your thinking. Even more thanks for having improved my code